# IBM i Access Client Solutions - Printer Output but using an API

Tags: db2

I want to replicate the functionality of the IBM i Access Client Solutions "Printer Output" tool that is used to retrieve PDF's of spooled files from our IBM Db2 environment. Instead of a user interface, I want to replicate the functionality as an API.

[image]

I want to construct an API which takes inputs such as the filter parameters pictured below:

[image]

The output of the API would be PDF(s) of the printer output spooled files that match the parameters specified.

I figure that if I am able to access the i Access Printer Output tool, then I should be able to use my credentials to access the spool files using an API or something like that.

Where would I start in constructing something like this?

Also, are there any IBM guides that contain relevant information? I have looked but been unsuccessful. The Programmer's Toolkit is, also, not available with my version of i Access.

Also, I don't have developer roles, so if this is possible, it would need to be something that I can do with little authority within the IBM i servers and the Access client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, IBM ACS is Java based.  Thus everything it does can be found in the IBM Toolbox for Java, aka JTOpen aka JT400.
http://jt400.sourceforge.net/

Documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=java-toolbox

You're going to want to look at the [reading a transformed spool file example](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzahh/transinstr.htm#transinstr)

The transformation actually happens on the IBM i side, by specifying the appropriate [workstation customization object](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=considerations-workstation-customizing-object-wscst-parameter), `QCTXPDF` in this case rather than the examples original `QWPTIFFG4`

```
// The following examples demonstrate how to set up a PrintParameterList to 
// obtain different transformations when reading spooled file data. In the code
// segments that follow, assume a spooled file already exists on a server, and 
// the createSpooledFile() method creates an instance of the SpooledFile class
// representing the spooled file.

// Create a spooled file
SpooledFile splF = createSpooledFile();

// Set up print parameter list
PrintParameterList printParms = new PrintParameterList();
printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_WORKSTATION_CUST_OBJECT, "/QSYS.LIB/QCTXPDF.WSCST");
printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_MFGTYPE, "*WSCST");

// Create a transformed input stream from the spooled file
PrintObjectTransformedInputStream is = splF.getTransformedInputStream(printParms);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply - I cannot wait to put this in to practice.

Comment: Apologies for the brief reply above - I posted prematurely.

I cannot wait to put this in to practice. My only issue is that I am very much a novice with Java and do not fully understand the process of referencing external classes/.jar files.  Will I need to use the entirety of the toolbox, or reference only a few specific classes/.jar files within my new class? I could not find documentation on what each specific .jar file contains so I am not sure which one to reference.

Comment: Following up: I figured out how to download and apply JT400 to my Java code. I am struggling to adjust the above code example to reference a specific, pre-existing spool file on the server. I can probably figure it out on my own, but just wanted to let you know that your answer has helped me immensely and has kick started my journey to figuring this out. Thanks again.